# Why FIFO file must be open to read before opening to write?

Tags: unix, file-io, kernel, pipe, fifo

Why function `open()` for FIFO in Unix is asymmetric? Why we need to first to open FIFO for reading and then for writing?
in `linux/fs/fifo.c` written:

```
/*
 *  O_RDONLY
 *  POSIX.1 says that O_NONBLOCK means return with the FIFO
 *  opened, even when there is no process writing the FIFO.
 */

/********
 *  O_WRONLY
 *  POSIX.1 says that O_NONBLOCK means return -1 with
 *  errno=ENXIO when there is no process reading the FIFO.
 */
```

Why can`t we firstly open for writing and after for reading?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is that many programs which are supposed to stay on the reading end also open it for writing, with the explicit purpose of avoiding a SIGPIPE/IO error when a client closes its writing end; as far as the kernel is concerned, there **is** a writer, except that it never writes, so in practice the read will see a blocking read.

Example: [clockspeed.c](http://cr.yp.to/clockspeed.html)